# Evaluating userid to true

Tags: coldfusion

I have a function which searches users by their e-mail. If a user is found, the function returns the userid. Otherwise it returns false.

How may I evaluate this userid which looks like `12202436120g1200069971` to true?

Comment: This makes no sense.  Can you reword the actual question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<cfif userid NEQ false>
  // do something
<cfelse>
  // do something else
</cfif>
```

Comment: I would also add a comment on the IF statement explaining that it's not a flat-out boolean evaluation (ie: from that statement, it looks like userid is a boolean, not a string which might happen to hold "false"), which explains what looks like a cortorted way of saying `<cfif userid>`, which is what someone might mistake it as. I think having a method which returns a mix of string or boolean is a poor approach (for this very reason), btw.

Comment: This is a good approach and will work fine, but I don't think its very expressive.  It implies that userid is a boolean value, which because of the power of ColdFusion many things are implicitly converted to booleans.  However, if you are mentally parsing the code in your head it reads "if the value of user id is false" in which you'll have to do the implicit conversion in your head.  Its why I take the approach I did in my answer.  It reads, "if the userid has a length do this other wise do this".  In my opinion it is more expressive but it is just an opinion.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly I'd do something like:

```
if(len(userid)){
   //true
}
else{
  //false
}
```

In ColdFusion 0 is false and any other number (negative or positive) is true.

Comment: I second bittersweetryan's answer with a minor clarification. It is not a great idea to return different variable types for a function (ex: string or boolean/false), or at least one this straight forward. Sending back a string that is either the userid or blank would be best, in which case you can use len() as stated.